# I need to merge data from 2 columns to another column. And then merge all rows of that added column into one cell in another table

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql-server, merge

I need to merge data from 2 columns to another column. And then merge all rows of that added column into one cell in another table..

Added two columns to one a column.!!
  to see image click [https://i.stack.imgur.com/srcrp.png]

**code used** :

`SELECT (CustomerName + ' ' + ContactName) as onecolumn from company_PR`

Now I need to merge all rows of that added column into one cell in another table.
[like shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajLBP.png)

Comment: `insert into AllTogether (onecolumn) SELECT (CustomerName + ' ' + ContactName) as onecolumn from company_PR` ?

Comment: This is a common SQL related question, one example with answer [is here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing this at the server side then one way of doing this is to use a cursor.

```
DECLARE @ListEntry varchar(100)
DECLARE @List varchar(1000)
DECLARE ENTRY_CURSOR CURSOR  FOR 
SELECT (CustomerName + ' ' + ContactName) as ListEntry from company_PR

SET @List = ''
OPEN ENTRY_CURSOR 
FETCH NEXT FROM ENTRY_CURSOR INTO @ListEntry 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS =0
BEGIN
    IF @List ='' 
    SET @List = @ListEntry  --Don't put a comma before the first entry on the list
    ELSE
    SET @List = @List +', '+ @ListEntry

    FETCH NEXT FROM ENTRY_CURSOR INTO @ListEntry 
END
CLOSE ENTRY_CURSOR 
DEALLOCATE ENTRY_CURSOR 
SELECT @List AS list
```